# Attaching Ec2 instances to Elastic beanstalk PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Before we send a push notification I am wanting to spin up a couple of extra instances behind the elastic beanstalk load balancer in order to handle the impending traffic load.

There doesn't seem to be anything in the Elastic beanstalk method that would deploy a new instance.

I have found in the AWS documentation that there is the ability to attach instances to an autoscaling group by specifying the ec2 IDs.

```
$result = $client->attachInstances(array(
    'InstanceIds' => array('string', ... ),
    // AutoScalingGroupName is required
    'AutoScalingGroupName' => 'string',
));
```

Am I correct in thinking that I would have to create a new eC2 instance, then attach it to the load balancer? or is there not a method in ElasticBeanstalk that would allow me to simply trigger a new instance?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to Beanstalk and updating the capacity?

Your best bet may be adding a one-time time based scaling policy. In this example, you can double your capacity 10 minutes before you send your email, then bring it back down to normal after 24 hours.

Comment: I was hoping to do this through the SDK if its possible

Comment: Which SDK? they should all have support for adding a scaling policy. As an example, here is the boto3 put scaling policy call: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.put_scaling_policy